# ASP.Net codebehind can't access component from page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

For an unknown reason, I have 1 page that I can't access by ID to any of the component.

Here is some informations. The page use asp:Content because the website use MasterPage. Inside the asp:Content, this page has a asp:FormView with some data that I cannot access from the CodeBehind.

Here is the Page declaration:

> 

Here is the code in the page behind that doesn't compile :

```
protected void FormView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateBirthdayValidator.MaximumValue = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yy");
}
```

Here is the error :

> Error 2   The name 'DateBirthdayValidator' does not exist in the current context

I have search in google, I got some answer about using FindControl but it doesn't work. Any idea?

### Edit1:

I can access the FormView1 component but no the validator inside the EditItemTemplate. How can I access control that is inside the EditTemplate?

### Edit2:

If I try: `FormView1.FindControl("DateBirthdayValidator")` it compile but always return null. So still doesn't work but at least I can access the FormView1...

Comment: other pages using the same master page work without problems?

Comment: Yeah but they doesn't have FormView... but yes I can access other component from other page. The problem is with this page :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected void FormView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(FormView1.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Edit)
        ((RangeValidator)FormView1.FindControl("DateBirthdayValidator")).MaximumValue = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yy");
}
```

The FormView doesn't have the control created until it's in the mode you want. Since the DateBirhdayValidator was in the Edit Mode, it required to have a validation in the CodeBehind to be sure to Find the control only when the state is in edit.

I found the solution [here](http://www.codenewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.aspnet.webcontrols/topic9174.aspx), see the post from Steven Cheng[MSFT].

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the validator you have declared in the form view does not really exist at the page level. It's a template that you define for your `FormView`. The parent control can instantiate a template (zero, one or more times, for instance think about each row in a `GridView`; and as a consequence, create its controls). You should try accessing it like:

```
// Replace RangeValidator with the actual validator type, if different.
var v = (RangeValidator)myFormView.Row.FindControl("DateBirthdayValidator");
v.MaximumValue = ...;
```

Note that to be able to do this, your form view should be in the mode you declared your validator in (you can check this with the `CurrentMode` property) and you should have already called `DataBind` to bind it to a data source (so that at least single row exists, and thus an instance of the template is created).

Comment: Ok but I can't access the component in any method (not only _PreRender).

Comment: @Daok: If the issue I said is the problem, it shouldn't work in any method. It's a compile time thing. At compile time, no such field is available for the base class

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `DateBirthdayValidator` declared in the aspx page?  Also check to ensure that Visual Studio create a corresponding `DateBirthdayValidator` declaration in the designer file for your page.  It sounds like most likely the designer file is missing the declaration for the control.

Comment: The ASPX has a DateBirhtdayValidator inside the EditItemTemplate of the FormView. By the way, I can access the FormView in the codebehind!?